# SKScene: find max position of SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm writing an App for iPad and iOS 10.
My App uses only one SKScene (size is 1300 by 1000).
I also use one camera defined like this:

```
myCamera=[[SKCameraNode alloc] init];
myCamera.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
self.camera=myCamera;
[self addChild:myCamera];
```

I use many SKSpriteNodes that the user can drag around (even beyond the size of the SKScene).

I also use:

```
[myCamera setScale:newScale];
```

to deal with pinch to zoom.

I need to know if there is a way to get the max X position of the node that is most distant from position 0,0 in the SKScene on the right hand side without having to read all node positions one by one.
And then do the same for the other three sides (up, left, down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep four floats minX, minY, maxX, maxY.  While the user is dragging a node, check if its position exceeds either max or is less than either min.  If so, update the corresponding value, e.g.

**EDIT** use `calculateAccumulatedFrame` to get the full extent of the node's descendants.

```
// assuming you have code like this already
skNodeThatIAmDragging.position = currentDragPosition;
CGRect frame = [skNodeThatIAmDragging calculateAccumulatedFrame];

if (self.maxX < frame.origin.x) {
    self.maxX = frame.origin.x;
}
if (self.minX > CGRectGetMaxX(frame)) {
    self.minX = CGRectGetMaxX(frame);
}
// ... and so on
```

Comment: Of course this is a possibile solution. But my SKSpriteNodes have child nodes an so the code for updating maxX would be more complicated.
I wonder if SKScene is aware of this maxX position already.
For example, I wonder if SKScene didChangeSize is called automatically or something like that if a node is outside the SKScene frame.

Comment: See edit.   Same idea, but use use calculateAccumulatedFrame to get the full extent of the node's descendants.  If your nodes geometry is fixed, you can cache this rect for each node to save computation.

Comment: Your suggestion is good but it doesn't work if the user drags a child node (that also has child nodes). In this case we should use also SKNode convertPoint:fromNode: to convert position to SKScene coordinates.

Comment: @danyadd, :-) double check your suggestion for the inequalities.   We care about the finding a node whose origin exceeds the max's or whose right edge is exceeded by the mins.  calculateAccumulated frame captures the extent of all of a node's descendants.

Comment: This solution also works for a case which you might not have considered: when the same node's descendants fall beyond both the max and the min values.  Consider that it's a little strange asking this question for nodes who's children are geometrically diverse.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll accept your answer. I still think that SKScene should help a little more in this matter.

Comment: Thanks.  I think that `accumulatedFrame` is pretty helpful, but I guess that's just me having low expectations.  You can call it anytime on the uppermost node to get the extents.